# Xcode Instruments- Trace file creation programmatically in XCUITest

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcuitest, xcode-instruments

I have written an XCUItest to test native IOS application. I was wondering if there is a way to create trace file by starting the trace at the start of XCUITest and ending the trace at the end of XCIUTest and save it in some path which i can open in the Instruments app later and analyze. In the instruments APP there is an option to mark generation , i would also like to know if that can be achieved as well.

Somewhere i saw that there is a framework called Instrument which i can leverage it to do such activity , however i am not able to import it in my XCUITest , neither i see any such framework in my Xcode.

Thanks
Ganesh